# Blender operations panel not showing up at all

Tags: interface, panel

The operations panel is not showing up at all. I know it does disappear if you click away but it is not showing up in the first place. I can press f9 and a window will show up but it does not stay. Please help[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **View** menu drop-down enable the **Adjust Last Operator** option:

[image]